# How to implement a multiple criteria in Where clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sapb1

I am wanting to see **ONLY** the documents where 3 criteria's are met but the 3 criteria's have multiple criteria's.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
t0.DocNum

FROM 
dbo.OIPF t0 inner join IPF2 t1 ON t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
inner join IPF1 t2 on t0.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry

WHERE 
(t1.OhType = 'W' and t1.CostSum > 0) and
(t1.OhType = 'F' and T1.CostSum > 0) and
(t1.OhType = 'Q' and T1.CostSum > 0)
```

This gives me **zero** results.  But to me that is how I would make sure that all 3 of these cost types have totals **greater than** 0.

Could any one help me on this?

Thanks!!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: My question is, how would you restructure the query to be able to say" WhatDocument has type A cost > $0 and type B cost is > $0 and Type C is > $0

Comment: Your query do exactly what you say. If you give more information about the tables. then there can be found more things that can causes issues

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different criteria. Try `or` but not `and`.

```
SELECT
t0.DocNum

FROM 
dbo.OIPF t0 inner join IPF2 t1 ON t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
inner join IPF1 t2 on t0.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry

WHERE

(t1.OhType = 'W' and t1.CostSum > 0) or
(t1.OhType = 'F' and T1.CostSum > 0) or
(t1.OhType = 'Q' and T1.CostSum > 0);
```

Comment: OP needs all 3 criteria to be met. This query wouldn't do that

Comment: @bksi there is no object which can fulfill the clause (t1.OhType = 'W' AND t1.OhType = 'F') hence AND will not work in that case. Sorry for the slow response lol

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
t0.DocNum
FROM dbo.OIPF t0 
inner join IPF2 t1 ON t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
--inner join IPF1 t2 ON t0.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry
WHERE t1.OhType in ('W' , 'F', 'Q') and t1.CostSum > 0
```

What you are trying to do is equivalent to this. Also, i am not sure why the table `IPF1` is being joined on, if it is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Alex_Bender's answer would be correct.

Another simpler way to express it which may be simpler to understand would be like this:

```
SELECT
t0.DocNum

FROM 
dbo.OIPF t0 inner join IPF2 t1 ON t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
inner join IPF1 t2 on t0.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry

WHERE t1.OhType IN ('W', 'F', 'Q')
AND t1.CostSum > 0
```

Comment: This would return result if one of the criteria is met. The OP needs all 3 to be met.

Comment: @bski: Clearly, a row can never be true for all 3 criteria at the same time.  So, I have to conclude that it's simply a matter of OP not expressing his intent very clearly. That's all.

Comment: That's why i asked him for details before put any answer ;)